# Need perl/shell script to compare 2 files

Tags: perl, shell, sed, awk, grep

Hi I have 2 files as below, I need script to compare those and find the match. How can I achieve this?

file1 as a.txt :

```
Anirban
Ball
Cat
Dog
cow
```

file2 as b.txt :

```
I am Anirban
I am Ball
I am Cat_cat
I am Dog
I am cow
I am horse
```

I want output like this :

```
I am Anirban
I am Ball
I am Dog
I am cow
```

I tried with `grep -f b a`, it did not give the exact match.

Comment: This is a quiet common question, that a goolge would have solved for you quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Like this can be a way:

```
$ grep -wf a.txt b.txt
I am Anirban
I am Ball
I am Dog
I am cow
```

On your solution you were not using `grep -w`, which is convenient. Also, note you were giving the files in the opposite order.

- `-f` is used to tell grep to obtain parameters from a file.
- `-w` matches whole words.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $NF in a' a.txt b.txt
```